# Overriding Like button URL

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I have a situation where the URL for a particular item can be different, depending on the search parameters used to find the item. I want to override the URL with one that uses the standard default parameters. Therefore, every write to the table will be to the same row, regardless of how the person got to that item.
This works when writing to the Facebook table but the page with the non standard default parameters' like count does not show the proper count from that table row. When  I bring up the page using the standard default parameters used in the overriding URL, the count shows correctly.
This indicates that Facebook can understand the override URL and write it to the table properly, it just can send that count back to the page that sent the like unless its URL is the same as the URL that is in the table.
Is there some parameter that needs to be used? Is this even possible?

Comment: You may want to give some background as to what framework your using. Your development env, etc... Your question could also benefit from formating (don't have everything all on one line). A well formated question will get much more interest, and most likely quicker responses.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any server side scripting , say java than you would replace the url in like button code . For example

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="<%= GetUrl(SearchParameter)%>" send="true" width="450" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>
```

And create a function that can return you url based on search parameter

String GetUrl(String SearchParameter){
......
}